# Show that $C-C=[-1,1].$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, cantor-set

Let $C$ to be the [Cantor middle third set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) in $[0,1]$.
Clearly every element of Cantor set has ternary representation and vice versa.

> **Question:** Show that 
>   $$C-C=[-1,1],$$
>   where $C-C = \{x-y:x,y\in C \}.$

My attempt: 
Since $C\subseteq [0,1],$ therefore 
$$C-C\subseteq [-1,1].$$
Now, let $z\in [-1,1].$
I can use the following fact 
$$C+C=[0,2].$$
Since $z+1\in [0,2],$ therefore, 
$$z+1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{3^k} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{b_k}{3^k}$$
where $a_k,b_k\in\{0,2\}$ for all natural number $k.$
Observe that 
$$z= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{3^k} - \left(1 - \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{b_k}{3^k}\right)$$
where 
$$1 - \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{b_k}{3^k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2-b_k}{3^k}$$
is an element of Cantor set, as $2-b_k\in\{0,2\}$ for all natural number $k.$
Therefore, $z\in C-C.$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: What you have written is true, though it covers only the *very* simple transition from $C+C=[0,2]$ to $C-C=[-1,1]$. Why do you think you can use $C+C=[0,2]$ without so much as a reference? It's not hard to prove, but it's a bit harder than the part you showed us.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: Because we have proven the fact $C+C=[0,2]$ in class. The question that I asked above comes after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof not starting from $C+C$ uses the [balanced ternary system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary), in which every number  $x\in [-1/2, 1/2]$ is represented as 
$$
x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n 3^{-n},\quad \epsilon_n\in \{-1, 0, 1\}
$$
Write each such $\epsilon_n$ as $(1-0)$ or $(0-1)$ or $(0-0)$ as appropriate, and redistribute the terms:
$$
x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n 3^{-n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n 3^{-n}
$$
with $a_n\in \{0, 1\}$ and $b_n\in \{0, 1\}$. It remains to multiply this by $2$, and the result follows: $2x = a-b$ where $a, b$ are in the Cantor set $C$.